# An identity with line integrals in complex analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, probability-theory

Show that for each $x \in \mathbb R$ and $n \in \mathbb N$, the second equality holds: $$f_n(x) \equiv \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-itx}}{2}\left(\frac{\sin t}{t} \right )^n \,dt = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \cos(tx) \left(\frac{\sin t}{t} \right )^n\,dt$$

This is the last part of the problem I'm working on, and it's to show that independent uniformly distributed on $(-1,1)$ random variables have density $f_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $$e^{-itx} = \cos{tx} - i \sin{tx}$$

Now note that $\sin{tx}$ is an odd function of $t$ regardless of $x$, and

$$\frac{\sin t}{t}$$ is even. Hence the integrand corresponding to the imaginary part is odd, and so integrates to $0$. The integrand corresponding to the real part is even, which gives us the change of bounds and removes the factor $\frac 1 2$.